# vertically align different size images in a figure* environment

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, subfloats

I have an `figure*` environment with the following

```
\begin{figure*}
    \centerline {
    \subfloat[1]{...}
    \subfloat[2]{...}
    }
\end{figure*}
```

The images are different heights.  How can I vertically align them? i.e. so the centre of each image is next to each other:

```
_____
|    |     _____  
|    |  _  |    |
|    |     |____|
|____|

     Fig. 1
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two different scenarios, independent of whether you use the `figure` or `figure*` environment (or any other float for that matter). The first allows you to move the entire label with the image, while the second keeps the image label at the same level as the other one:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{subfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig
\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\myimage}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \savebox{\myimage}{\hbox{\rule{150pt}{150pt}}}% Store largest image
  \subfloat[First]{\usebox{\myimage}} \quad
  \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\ht\myimage-.5\height\relax}{\subfloat[Second]{\rule{100pt}{100pt}}}
  \caption{This is a figure.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \savebox{\myimage}{\hbox{\rule{150pt}{150pt}}}% Store largest image
  \subfloat[First]{\usebox{\myimage}} \quad
  \subfloat[Second]{\raisebox{\dimexpr.5\ht\myimage-.5\height\relax}{\rule{100pt}{100pt}}}
  \caption{This is a figure.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The idea is to store the largest image in a box (`\myimage`). Then you raise the smaller image (50% of the largest box) - (50% of the smaller box) or, in LaTeX terms,

```
\dimexpr.5\ht\myimage-.5\height\relax
```

`.5\ht\myimage` refers to 50% of the height of `\myimage`, while `.5\height` refers to 50% of the height of the *current* box (contained within the `\raisebox` command). You first have to "create" a box using `\newsavebox`, and assign something to it using `\savebox`.

In the example above, [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) was not required since no images were included (I used `\rule{<width>}{<height>}`). However, you'll need to use it if you include images.

Other options might also be possible via [`floatrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow).