# Top alignment of subfigure

Tags: vertical-alignment, subfloats

For some reason I'm not able to have a top alignment of figures using `subfigure` and the environmental option `[t]`. I have search the internet for solutions and found them pretty complex for such a simple and general problem... What is the simple solution?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering

\begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{calCurve.pdf}
\caption{Caption 1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{anova.pdf}
\caption{Caption 2}
\end{subfigure}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Check this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101858/make-two-figures-aligned-at-top

Comment: Thank you. That will do it. I Guess the problem gets a bit more complicated if you the caption align as well...

Comment: My very strong recommendation here is to use the excellent package [subcaption](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption). It is perfect for this. Check for the `\subcaptionbox`-command in section 4/page 6.

Comment: @henry - The OP *is* using the `subcaption` package.

Comment: You may have come across a bug in the `subcaption` package when the `draft` or `demo` options are set.

Comment: Related: [Vertically align different size images in a `figure*` environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41166/5764)

Comment: Related: [Vertical alignment of two images of different vertical size](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/239128/5764)

Comment: @Mico Oh you are right. My intern must have overlooked that. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give `floatrow` a roll:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{caption,floatrow}

\DeclareCaptionSubType[alph]{figure}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=colon}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=brace,labelsep=space,labelfont=bf}
\floatsetup[subfigure]{capposition=bottom,heightadjust=all,valign=t}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
  {\begin{subfloatrow}
      \ffigbox
        {\caption{First subfigure}}%
        {\rule{3cm}{3cm}}

        \ffigbox
        {\caption{Second subfigure with more Text so we have a line break}}%
        {\rule{1.5cm}{1.5cm}}
  \end{subfloatrow}}
  {\caption{Two figures}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]