# Vertically aligned subfloat caption prevent wrap

Tags: floats, line-breaking, subfloats

I have searched around for this but couldn't figure out the solution for my particular document.

Using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41166/vertically-align-different-size-images-in-a-figure-environment) answer I have placed two images of different width side by side.

I would like the text of image (a) to not wrap. Ideally, I would like the image to be centered above the non-wrapped caption.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\myimage}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \savebox{\myimage}{\hbox{\rule{150pt}{150pt}}}% Store largest image
  \subfloat[First caption text is a bit longer and wraps.]{\usebox{\myimage}} \quad
  \subfloat[Second fits on one line.]{\raisebox{\dimexpr.5\ht\myimage-.5\height\relax}{\rule{100pt}{20pt}}}
  \caption{This is a figure.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Text wrapping]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add some space on the side of the larger image. This will make the caption not wrap:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}

\newsavebox{\myimage}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \savebox{\myimage}{\hbox{\rule{150pt}{150pt}}}% Store largest image
  \subfloat[First caption text is a bit longer and wraps.]{\quad\usebox{\myimage}\quad} \quad
  \subfloat[Second fits on one line.]{\raisebox{\dimexpr.5\ht\myimage-.5\height}{\rule{100pt}{20pt}}}
  \caption{This is a figure.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Above I used `\quad` on either side of the left image. For more options, see [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5764)

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I completely forgot about \quad...