# Aligning subfig captions vertically

Tags: captions, subcaption, subfig

I am using IEEETrans and the recommended subfig package. I have tikz graphics in subfigures, and I really want them to be aligned by their top bounding box (so that the nodes align).

The problem is, when I do that, the captions are not aligned anymore (see MWE). How can I have my cake and eat it too.

MWE:

```
\documentclass\[journal,compsoc,onecolumn,draftclsnofoot\]{IEEEtran}

\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
\usepackage\[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfon
t=sf,textfont=sf\]{subfig}
\else
\usepackage\[caption=false,font=footnotesize\]{subfig}
\fi

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,calc,patterns,matrix,backgrounds,chains}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}
        \subfloat\[A\]{
\begin{tikzpicture}\[baseline=(current bounding box.north)\]
\matrix (m)\[matrix of nodes\]
{
    a\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}           
}
        \subfloat\[B\]{
\begin{tikzpicture}\[baseline=(current bounding box.north)\]
\matrix (m)\[matrix of nodes\]
{
    a\\
    b\\
    c\\
    d\\
    e\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
        }

    \end{figure*}
\end{document}]
```

Generated Output:
[image]

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41172/134144. For top alinged images with bottom aligned captions, you just remove the `.5` as follows: `\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\myimage-\height\relax}`. Here is also another alternative using `subcaption` instead of `subfig`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152818/134144

Comment: I tried the raisebox trick to no avail. Also, the IEEETrans documentation suggests to use subfig, so I'd like to stick to subfig.

Comment: I got the raisebox trick to work by removing the baseline parameter from tikzpicture. Please make your comment into answer so you can get credit!

Answer (score 1):

The following is a modified version of a solution originally posted by Werner here: [vertically align different size images in a figure* environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41172/134144)

```
\documentclass[journal,compsoc,onecolumn,draftclsnofoot]{IEEEtran}

\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\else
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\fi

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,calc,patterns,matrix,backgrounds,chains}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\myimage}   
\begin{figure*}
 \centering
 \savebox{\myimage}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m)[matrix of nodes]
    {
    a\\
    b\\
    c\\
    d\\
    e\\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
 } % Store largest image
  \subfloat[A]{\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\myimage-\height\relax}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m)[matrix of nodes]
    {
    a\\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }} \quad
  \subfloat[B]{\usebox{\myimage}}
  \caption{This is a figure.}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]